# PyTorch Dataloader ignores FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I have a custom Pytorch dataset and its corresponding dataloader. However, when I iterate over the dataloader, it seems like it skips the loop entirely. I have checked that the length of the dataloader is not 0.

I have a custom dataset which only given a folder lists all the images in the folder, and then returns the image and the filepath each time it is called.

```
class BBoxDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, path_list):
        super().__init__()

        self.img_dirs = path_list
        self.update_img_paths()

    def update_img_paths(self):
        self.img_paths = []
        for img_dir in self.img_dirs:
            files = glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, "*.jpg"))
            for file in files:
                self.img_paths.append(file)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        filepath = self.img_paths[idx]
        img = Image.open(filepath).convert("RGB")
        return img, filepath
```

I have created a custom dataloader for the same and a function to return the constructed dataloader.

```
def get_dataloader(image_paths, batch_size: int, shuffle: bool = dataset_settings.random_shuffle,
                    num_workers: int = 0, phase: str = 'infer', sampler: Sampler = None) -> None:
    dataset = BBoxDataset(path_list=image_paths)
    drop_last = False if phase == 'infer' else True
    shuffle = False if phase == 'infer' else True
    kwargs_dl = dict(num_workers=num_workers, batch_size=batch_size, pin_memory=True, shuffle=shuffle, drop_last=drop_last, sampler=sampler)
    if sampler is not None: 
        kwargs_dl['sampler'] = sampler(dataset, shuffle=shuffle)
        del kwargs_dl['shuffle']
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, **kwargs_dl)
    return dataloader
```

However, when I import the try to loop through the dataloader, it does not even enter the loop. In my case, the "MLN" is not printed, neither is the data from the batch.

```
infer_dataloader = get_dataloader(dataset_path, batch_size=1)
for batch, batch_data in enumerate(infer_dataloader):
    print("MLN")
    image, filepath = batch_data
    print(image, filepath)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can anyone help?